# elasticsearch.js failover for unresponsive node

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, failover

I'm using elasticsearch.js in a node.js server with 3 hosts, configured in that way:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var config = {
    hosts: [
        'host1',
        'host2',
        'host3',
    ],
    apiVersion: '6.1'
}

var elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client(config);
```

If one of these hosts is down the client get a timeout error, how can I avoid it?

I tried the ping command and it did't responded without error.

Is there a way to configure a generic failover that calls the next host if one is down?

Thanks.